# sitemap com PHP - Ajuste no htaccess

Tags: php, htaccess

Tenho este trecho no `.htaccess` que está funcionando para a minha atual necessidade:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$

RewriteRule . index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Estou montando um arquivo em PHP que gera sitemap dinâmico e preciso adicionar essa linha depois do `RewriteEngine On`:

```
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ gera_xml.php [L]
```

A idéia é que, se eu coloque `www.site.com.br/sitemap.xml`, ele apresente o sitemap em XML, mas não funciona de jeito nenhum.

Já troquei de posição e nada.
Troquei a instrução e deu erro na página.